# Create Multiple Queues at Once c++

Tags: c++, for-loop, queue

Is there a way I can create multiple queues at once?

For Example my program will ask. How many queues the user wants, if he submits 3 then it will create 3 queues that look like this.

```
queue<int> queue1;

queue<int> queue2;

queue<int> queue3;
```

Do I create a for loop to do this? Or is there another way to do so?

```
for (int i = 0; i<userInput; i++)
{
   queue<int> queue[i];
}
```

Would the above work? Basically ask the user how many queues they want created, and it will create them based on his input.

Comment: `std::vector<std::queue<int>>`

Comment: To generalize, the answer to, "How do I create a dynamic number of X," is most usually `std::vector<X>`

Comment: Copying an old question does not make a good impression.

Comment: Jeeze. Word for word or close enough that I can't tell the difference at a glance. 7 years apart. Clearly not someone trying to get around the question cool-down period.

Answer (score 0):

You must use a container of `queue`s. Example:

```
std::vector<std::queue<int>> queues;
```

This std::vector (defined in `<vector>`) is a dynamic array of queues, and you can add a new queue like this:

```
queues.push_back(std::queue<int>::queue());
```

Fully functional example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    int number;
    std::cin >> number;
    std::vector<std::queue<int>> queues;
    for (int i = 0; i < number; ++i) {
        queues.push_back(std::queue<int>::queue());
    }
}
```

Or

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    int number;
    std::cin >> number;
    std::vector<std::queue<int>> queues;
    for (int i = 0; i < number; ++i) {
        std::queue<int> current;
        queues.push_back(current);
    }
}
```

You cannot (at compile time) create multiple instances of an object when depending on USER INPUT. You have to use some sort of containter, like a `std::vector`, a `std::list` or (purely for a joke) a `std::queue` of `std::queue`s of `int`s.

For a `std::vector`, you can access a certain queue like this:

```
queues[0];
```

In this example. we will get the first queue. Note that `std::vector` is range-checked.

**Note:** For the std::vector, you can initialize it like this:

```
std::vector<std::queue<int>> queues(number);
```

To have it start out with `number` elements.